# Drawing too much current from a SATA power Y-cable?

Tags: current, sata

I'm planning to use a Y-cable to split one of the power connectors inside of a notebook. Now if I connect a harddrive to the Y-cable, could another device soldered to the Y-cable draw so much current that the harddrive fails or something? Also, does anyone of you know how much current is provided though the SATA power cables on a regular notebook?
[image]

Comment: even with all the stories of laptop meltdowns, you're still willing to risk it?

Comment: sorry, not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: how much extra current are you planning to draw?

Comment: At 6V around 200mA, but it could peak up to 550mA. At 12V about half of that (a little bit more).

Comment: Forivin - "At 12V [...]" - FYI you don't have access to a 12V supply on the SATA cable of any laptop which I have worked on (or seen the schematic diagram of). It is not required for 2.5" SATA drives (as @Passerby notes below) and my experience is that there is simply no +12V power rail on a laptop motherboard, since no internal components require that voltage.

Comment: Forivin - I notice that you have deliberately not mentioned a specific laptop. Would you be consider a solution (potentially two) but which would only apply to limited (potentially very limited) models of laptops? Or are you looking only for a generic solution which could be used with any laptop? What level of guarantee of success are you expecting from any suggested solution? Does your device absolutely require 6V _and_ 12V as you mentioned earlier, or would you consider designing it to generate whatever it needs from a 5V supply? How long are the high-current peaks that you mentioned?

Comment: Can you disclose what the additional device is, to help readers with better understanding what its power requirements are likely to be?

Comment: The supply voltage doesn't really matter too much. It can be between 6V and 16V. And if it is not in that range, I would simply use a step-up/down converter.

Comment: Well I left the model because I thought it wouldn't be of any help, but it is an `HP Pavilion g6-2348SG`.

Comment: Just use an external drive bay. Forget the hacking... There are so many variables that you add when you throw a DC to DC into your laptop, the laptop was tested with specific current requirements in mind. You don't have the schematics for the motherboard. Just use an external drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could another device soldered to the Y-cable draw so much current that the harddrive fails or something?

Yes.

> Also, does anyone of you know how much current is provided though the SATA power cables on a regular notebook?

The engineers who designed the laptop. No one else knows. Laptops do not have a standard power specification like a desktop does with ATX or similar supplies. There is no labeled current output, no overly gracious power source. They are designed to a single goal, not open-ended like expandable desktop supplies are.

It's going to be at least 120% of the rated current of the existing drive (20% safety margin) **if you're lucky**.

Comment: So you can't normally expect 2 harddrives to work on the same sata power cable?

Comment: @Forivin from an undocumented supply, no. And that's not even counting how are you going to connect 2 SATA ***data*** cables to it? You'd be better off with a USB to SATA like http://www.uittek.com/usb-30-to-sata-157-pin-data-and-power-y-cable-adapter-for-25-inch-hdd-ssd_p729.html and stick with 2.5" (laptop) SATA drives that do not need 12V.

Comment: Is there a safe way to find out how much I can draw from it? And what if I'm not using the USB ports on my notebook. Could I then assume that I could draw more current from the SATA power?

Comment: The USB2 port on the right of my notebook gives me up to 2.5W and the USB3 port on the other side around 4.8W.

Comment: @Forivin - "[...] what if I'm not using the USB ports on my notebook. Could I then assume that I could draw more current from the SATA power?" No, you can't assume that. There are often individual limits for different parts of the laptop - using less current in part X doesn't necessarily mean you can use more current in part Y. The increased voltage drop along PCB tracks is one obvious example, but there are others. Again - you would need to reverse-engineer the schematic and PCB (or ask the designers) of each specific laptop where you want to make your modification, for a definite answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a spec. sheet for sata cable. http://www.calgreg.com/circuit-assembly/sata-specification.pdf

The current rating is 1 amp for that particular cable.

Apparently 1.5 A is the spec. from SATA. according to: 
http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Serial_ATA_(SATA,_Serial_Advanced_Technology_Attachment)

NOTE: This is 1.5 A per. cable meaning with 3 wire supply one could potentially draw 4.5 A...

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for the crappy picture-quality, but I had a server that mysteriously powered down in my co-lo a few years ago -- it was an old tower I had used for a special where the datacenter had some spare shelves for tower co-location.

The first two their tech sent me (a little blurry):
[image: cable1]
[image: cable2]

And the victim drive (I still have at my desk):
[image: drive]

Be careful about the quality of cable you use, in addition to the already mentioned facts above that it's unknown what kind of margins the laptop designers provided on their voltage regulators. In this case, it was probably a poorly constructed Y-adapter, but in your case, you may keep triggering over-current protection or something similar internally.